# \multicolumn error in tabular

Tags: tables

In awesome-cv, the defination is

```
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

This can be used as

```
\cventry
{Variable number 1} 
{Variable number 2} 
{Variable number 3} 
{Variable number 4} 
{
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Variable number 5}
\end{cvitems}
}
```

Variable number 2 supposed took whole width of `\textwidth` if variable number 3 is empty. So I use `\multicolumn`.
But the error occurred.

```
**Overfull \hbox (1.46pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 77--77
[]$[]$ $[]$$[]$ 
 Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.24 }**




  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3#2}}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        {%
          \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}
          {%
          \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}\entrytitlestyle{#2} \\
          }
          { 
          \entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
          }
          \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\
        }
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

I hope my error can be pointed out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't use \multicolumn inside an \ifthenelse. \ifthenelse is not expandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is better to proivide a complete test file but here the error is

```
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}
          {%
          \multicolumn{2}{
```

`\multicolumn` has to be the first thing in its cell, if you have any non-expandable tokens before this, the cell starts and can no longer be changed to a spanning cell.

`\ifnthenelse` does not work by expansion and makes multiple internal definitions so prevents the use of `\multicolumn`.

there are expandable tests that you could use, perhaps using the ones from `etoolbox`, it depends on the intention of this code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which clears things out. But in this case, how can it to be worked out?

Comment: maybe I can pull the condition out of table.